# TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, npm, integration-testing

I am a beginner and I have to check some ReactJS components by doing automated tests. This is my first one, I expect to success to login with good e-mail and password.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Login from '../Login';

it('should log in user in valid session', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    request(Login)
        .send({"email": "xxx@xxx.com", "password": "1234"});
    ReactDOM.render(<Login message={"The user is connected"} />, div);
});
```

But when I use **npm run test**, it returns me the following sentences:

```
 FAIL  src/components/test/Login.test.js   ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

      at getApiHeader (src/libraries/global.js:312:77)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/libraries/global.js:325:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Login.js:2:41)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/test/Login.test.js:3:40)
```

Do you have an idea of what happened? I didn't find any answer corresponding to what I did. Thank you!

Comment: share `Login.js`. When is a `split` done?

Comment: at least it means that the type of value you are trying to split is not `string`